# Basic4Android PNG compression

Tags: compression, png, basic4android

Android seems to visibly reduce the quality of PNG files at compile time.

I have an aplication working with a canvas object. The process writes canvas data over a PNG file which has smaller dimensions than the canvas. Writing process repeats according to user events more than once (maybe 20 times according to user). But after every writing process, image quality becomes worse and worse.It becomes pixelated.

Is there any way to turn off or disable compression for this?

```
EditingPartMutable_Bitmap.WriteToStream(out, 100, "PNG")
'quality = 100 didn't worked either
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG is a lossless format and as such the quality setting is ignored. The pixelated effect you are getting must be due to another reason.

Comment: Unless, perhaps, the original PNG used a palette?